# RestTemplate seems to keep Authorization header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm using Spring 4 RestTemplate to do some server-side API calls.

The `RestTemplate` instance is a custom one (not Spring Boot default) using Apache HttpClient created as follows:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;
...
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                                            .setConnectionManager(cm)
                                            .build();
```

Some of the API calls use HTTP Basic Authentication and thus need to have an Authorization header.  I'm adding this on a `RequestEntity` and then performing an `exchange()` call on the `RestTemplate` and this works fine.

```
RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity;
requestEntity = RequestEntity.get(uri)
                             .accept(MediaType.valueOf("application/repository.folder+json"))
                             .acceptCharset(UTF_8)
                             .header("Accept-Encoding", "")
                             .header("Authorization", apiBasicAuthHeader())
                             .build();
```

Some other API calls (to the same backend server) should not use HTTP Basic Authentication and instead use a pre-authenticated token supplied as a request parameter.

```
RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity = RequestEntity.get(uriWithToken)
                                                 .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                 .acceptCharset(UTF_8)
                                                 .header("Accept-Encoding", "")
                                                 .build();

operations.exchange(requestEntity, ResourceLookupResults.class)
```

This also works fine by itself.

However, if I do an API call using the Authorization header first and then try to do one with the pre-authenticated token (with the same `RestTemplate`), it seems that the Authorization header is still sent on the 2nd request.  I'd expect the header added to the `RequestEntity` to be added only for that specific request and not for subsequent requests that don't need it.  Why is this and what is the best way to avoid this (like using separate `RestTemplate` instances)?

Comment: Please show the code and also which http client you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated to answer both your questions.

Comment: You are using Apache HTTP Client, which uses a pool. The headers are being set on the connection and connections can be reused.

Comment: @M.Deinum So headers set on RequestEntity are not per-request?  One has to explicitly add an empty `Authorization` header on the following request in order to clear it?

Comment: I suspect that there is some caching going on or reusing of parts of the `RequestEntity` in your code. Could you try without Apache HTTP Client and use the default HTTP connection from the JDK. Just to figure out if this is a HTTP Component issue or Spring or maybe your own code.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm going to try to wire two separate RestTemplate instances (with their own HTTP Client with separate connection pool). But upon further investigation it seems to be an issue with the backend API server (JasperSoft report server) as subsequent requests with the token even from the broswer (using JasperSoft VisualJS) have issues with authentication. I pre-authenticate on the server side using the token, do an API call using basic auth, then some calls with the token again.  When I leave out the call using basic auth, everything is fine also in the browser. Will keep you posted here.

Comment: @M.Deinum the issue with the request from the browser (VisualJS) was unrelated.  Using separate (identical) RestTemplate instances for both types of requests, each with their own connection pool, solves (or rather avoids) the issue.